# What can we do to promote the Gaming.StackExchange Battlefield 3 Server?

Tags: discussion

We have a lovely 32-player server generously provided to our community, but I don't think I've ever seen enough players to even start a game!

We currently have a very lovely ad airing on our network:

[image]

But is there anything else we can do to promote it?

Comment: One idea, related to my meta post for the Skyrim:MW3 promotion would be to at least target those ads better and show them specifically for BF3 questions. At the momemt they're shown randomly as far as I understand

Comment: Damn. Wish I could play on this server. Damn America. y u be so far away!?!

Comment: Likewise Smooth...likewise

Comment: I'd play on it if it weren't I only have a copy of the game for xbox :(

Answer (score 6):

I've had the server on my favorites list since Jeff tweeted about it the night it was created.  I've been on it for a total of 5 minutes or so, and the entire time was spent waiting for more people to sign on to join me.  Getting servers popular is an extremely difficult thing to do, since people will almost always choose mostly-full servers over empty servers.

In my mind, the best way we can promote the site is *play on it*.  Advance-scheduled Game Ons will be useful for this, but only for a few hours out of the week.  Is there any precedent for having pickup-type Game Ons?  Say one of the admins of the steam group is interested in playing, an event starts immediately and notifications go out to the group members.  If I were looking to play, I would be much more likely to get on the gaming.SE server if I knew that there would be people there when I get on.

Comment: Agree 100% with this. How would we organize this?

Comment: We should definitely try to officiate the organization of pick-up gaming, beyond "hay guise, we are playing X" in chat.  Six of us or so were playing Terraria last night - if we had anything set up we could have done that then, too.

Answer (score 0):

I've promoted it on the [facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/GamingStackExchange/154617661300474), but since we only have 13 people following it so far, I'm not sure how helpful this will be.

Comment: Fourteen now.  And you really should use that FB page more often!  Promote!  Promote!  Promote!  Post great questions!  Post great answers!  Get news of our awesomeness out to the world!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this server on xbox or just PC?

Comment: Just PC, I'm afraid.